# Client's BufferedInputStream.read() while loop never stops

Tags: java, file-io, file-transfer

**I EDITED CODE**

I'm making file transfer program with java

I have to send 21 files.

my code stops at Client's while loop in `run()`

*(It doesn't print **"file receive complete"**)* <- see `run()` in Client

**Server's CODE**

```
class SendFileThread extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket fileTransferServerSocket;
    private Socket fileTransferSocket;
    private BufferedReader requestReader;
    private PrintWriter requestAnswerer;
    private BufferedOutputStream fileWriter;
    private int fileTransferPort = 12345;

    public SendFileThread() {
        try {
            fileTransferServerSocket = new ServerSocket(fileTransferPort);
            fileTransferSocket = fileTransferServerSocket.accept();
            requestReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileTransferSocket.getInputStream()));
            fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(fileTransferSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void CloseTransferStream() {
        try {
            requestAnswerer.close();
            requestReader.close();
            fileWriter.close();
            fileTransferSocket.close();
            fileTransferServerSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void SendFile(String filename) {
        try {
            File file = new File(CLIENT_PATH + "/" + filename);
            BufferedInputStream fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

            int packet;

            while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1)
                fileWriter.write(packet);

            fileWriter.flush();
            fileReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        //System.out.print(filename + " send complete (" + count + " times)");
    }

    public void ListenForRequester() {
        try {
            String input;
            while((input = requestReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(input.equals("request file")) {
                    SendFile(requestReader.readLine());
                }
                else if(input.equals("end transfer"))
                    break;
                else {
                    System.out.println("Something wrong");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        ListenForRequester();
        CloseTransferStream();
    }
}
```

**Client's CODE**

```
class ReceiveFileThread extends Thread {
    private Socket fileTransferSocket;
    private int fileTransferPort = 12345;
    private BufferedInputStream fileReader;
    private PrintWriter fileRequester;

    public ReceiveFileThread() {
        try {
            fileTransferSocket = new Socket(serverIP, fileTransferPort);
            fileRequester = new PrintWriter(fileTransferSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(fileTransferSocket.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void CloseTransferStream() {
        try {
            fileRequester.close();
            fileReader.close();
            fileTransferSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void RequestFile(String filename) {
        fileRequester.println("request file");
        fileRequester.println(filename);    
    }

    public synchronized void SendEndMsg() {
        fileRequester.println("end transfer");
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0;i < fileList.size();i++) {
            String filename = (String)fileList.get(i);
            RequestFile(filename);

            try {
                BufferedOutputStream fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(PROGRAM_PATH + "/" + filename)));

                int packet = 0;

                while((packet = fileReader.read()) > -1)
                    fileWriter.write(packet);

                System.out.println("file receive complete");

                fileWriter.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SendEndMsg();           
        CloseTransferStream();
    }
}
```

It became 5 days that this error bothers me :(

Could anyone save me from this error?

Comment: In your `SendFile(...)` method you are closing `fileWriter` which closes the socket's output stream and that can't be reopened.

Comment: However if I make `fileWriter` before `run()` and close it at `CloseTransferStream()`, **Client**'s while loop never stops. @Titus

Comment: Yes you are right, in order to send multiple files you will have to send the file's size first and then read that many bytes from the input stream into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the socket's output stream will close the socket, In order to send multiple files you will have to make a couple of changes.

Server:
Before you start to send a file, send that file's length.

Client:
After you receive the file's length start to read that many bytes from the input stream and save them to a file, when you're done read the next file's length.